# Differentiation of composite function within composite function

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

I was asked to differentiate $((1-3x)^5-x^2)^4$ with respect to x, I thought that I would have to apply chain rule to the internal function before moving on to the outside. However, the answer was $-4((1-3x)^5-x^2)^3(15(1-3x)^4+2x)$. How was this achieved so simply?

Comment: A quick check says the answer is clearly wrong... unless perhaps you misread the question?

Comment: yes you can do it with the chain rule, like unwrapping a parcel

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add the second part of the answer

Answer (score 1):

The answer is most probably wrong.

The common method to do this type of problems is by applying the **chain rule**.

Let,$y=[(1-3x)^5-x^2]^4$ and let,$z=(1-3x)^5-x^2$

So,$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dz}\cdot\frac{dz}{dx}\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dz}z^4\cdot[\frac{d}{dx}[(1-3x^5)-x^2]]=4z^3\cdot[\frac{d}{dx}[(1-3x^5)-x^2]]$$.

Now,you can continue as usual.(Don't forget to substitute the $z$ at last).

Comment: ok thanks! I think I get it now

Comment: Typo: $z^5$ should be $z^4$, which changes your derivative from $5z^4$ to $4z^3$

Answer (score 1):

---

The "official" answer seems to be correct. Awkward image of derivation follows:

[image: image of wordpad text]